# Custom event type on wayland/weston

Tags: wayland, weston

As far as I can see Wayland/weston support only limited events type
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/ch04.html#sect-Protocol-Input 
There are mouse, keyboards and touches.
No joysticks, no custom event type 
Is it possible to extend weston by some custom event type? 
Maybe a kind of a plugin?